# Barcode scanner click function in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm new vb.net and currently I'm developing a barcode scanner system where user will scan barcode on textbox. If it is a new barcode, it will be inserted into database and shown in the gridview else the recheckIn column will be updated to current date and CheckOut column will empty. The problem is the backend code that I did is OnButtonclick event. How it is possible to perform functions using barcode scanner without button click ? For example, if user click the barcode scanner twice it will show inserted barcode list on a gridview and if three times it will change the color of checkout button and update the checkout column to current date on the gridview.

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Text

Public Class _Default
    Inherits Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        If Label1.Visible = True Then
            Label1.Visible = False
        ElseIf Label1.Visible = False Then
            Label1.Visible = True
        End If

        If TextBox2.Visible = True Then
            TextBox2.Visible = False
        ElseIf TextBox2.Visible = False
            TextBox2.Visible = True
        End If

        Button1.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Color, "green")
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=EQUALIZER;Initial Catalog=Barcodeapp;Integrated Security=True")
        Dim cmd1 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("Select * from barscan", con)
        con.Open()
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please fill-up fields!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Add LOTID!")
        Else
            Dim theQuery As String = "SELECT Barcode FROM barscan WHERE Barcode=@Barcode"
            Dim cmd2 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(theQuery, con)
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Barcode", TextBox1.Text)


            Using reader As SqlDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader()

                If reader.HasRows Then
                    Dim theQuery2 As String = "Update barscan SET RecheckIn=GETDATE() WHERE Barcode=@Barcode"
                    Dim cmd3 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(theQuery, con)
                    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Barcode", TextBox1.Text)
                Else

                    Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=EQUALIZER;Initial Catalog=Barcodeapp;Integrated Security=True"
                    Using cn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
                        cn.Open()
                        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
                        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO barscan (Date,Barcode,Location,CheckIn) VALUES(@Date,@Barcode,@Location,@CheckIn)"

                        Dim param3 As New SqlParameter()
                        param3.ParameterName = "@Date"
                        param3.Value = Date.Today()
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(param3)

                        Dim param1 As New SqlParameter()
                        param1.ParameterName = "@Barcode"
                        param1.Value = TextBox1.Text.Trim()
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(param1)

                        Dim param2 As New SqlParameter()
                        param2.ParameterName = "@Location"
                        param2.Value = TextBox2.Text.Trim()
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(param2)

                        Dim param4 As New SqlParameter()
                        param4.ParameterName = "@CheckIn"
                        param4.Value = Date.Today()
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(param4)

                        cmd.Connection = cn
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        cn.Close()
                    End Using

                    If barapp.Visible = True Then
                        barapp.Visible = False
                    ElseIf barapp.Visible = False Then
                        barapp.Visible = True
                    End If
                End If
            End Using

            con.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

[User Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWEee.png)

Answer (score 2):

It all really depends on the barcode scanner, some have COM interfaces you can query directly and others are HID interfaces that act like a keyboard (a lot can be configured either way).

I will assume it is a common generic HID interface.  Most of these can be configured with a SUFFIX code that also gets sent.

What you will want to do is make sure the SUFFIX code is programmed with data you can easily detect (usually a TAB or ENTER key).

Once you have the suffix programmed into the barcode reader, you will want to use either the KeyPress or KeyDown event of the textbox, and once it detects the SUFFIX code, trigger the action to be taken.

For the scenario you listed, I like to make the action it's own function, and have the Button and the Key(Press/Down) event call that function.

Answer (score 0):

The way I have often detected input from a barcode scanner is to use the `TextChanged` event. If someone is typing a value in, you will get this event for every key press but if they are using the scanner, you will get this event once for a single scan. What this means is that you can look at what the text was before and what it is now and determine if this was from a barcode scanner as opposed to manual input.

This will also work against a PASTE operation but in my eyes they should work the same as a scan. Bonus!